# load entries by batches

Tags: channel-entries, javascript, memory-limit, memory

I have a channel entries tag that has to load (sometimes) more than 3000 entries and I'm running into memory issues.

I'm looking for a way to build the page by batches (with javascript?) and display some kind of animated icon while the wait.

Waiting is not a problem, as long as the page does not crash...

Comment: What is the final purpose of this page? Is it being saved to local disk in website (html) format, or is it just for browsing? If all of these entries have to be loaded on to one page, it gets difficult. Is pagination / lazy loading (think infinite scroll or a **Load More Entries** button at the bottom that grabs them async) a viable option for your display goals?

Comment: It's a products list : reference, price, type, etc. boring tabular data.  Yes, kind  of lazy load, but it  should load itself, without the user clicking a button.

Comment: Hi Laurent. Did you manage to find a solution to this. Id love to know :)

Comment: @Kippi Unfortunately not, because resolving the issue on the server side was faster. Never found the time to investigate more...

Answer (score 1):

You can use here LAZY LOAD or INFINITE SCROLL (Just like automatic pagination)

https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/